# linphone: remove/hide "default identity"

Tags: voip, sip

[Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) 3.6.1 automatically generates a computer-local SIP identity called "Default Identity".

"Real" SIP accounts you have at a VoIP provider need to be created as "Proxy accounts":

[image]

The main window has a dropdown to select the current identity:

[image]

Is there a way to disable the "Default Identity"? I cannot use it to make calls, so I see no need for it. It just complicates the interface.

Comment: provided you have a FQDN, or even your own domain, it makes sense.  If you had `cweiske.com`, for example, it would have more utility.

Comment: I would like to do the same, have you found a method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to hide the default identity with linphone 4.2: Edit linphonerc config file and add:

```
[ui]
show_local_sip_account=0
```

(Taken from https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop/issues/376#issuecomment-845837863)